# Как отличаются поток сообщения от потока файла в чате

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tcp, чат

Как в программе  отличаются потоки сообщения и файла?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TCPchatic
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 20113);
    delegate void RecieveTextDelegate(string text);
    RecieveTextDelegate param;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        server.Start();
        param = new RecieveTextDelegate(textBoxChat.AppendText); 
        BeginAcceptTcpClient();
    }
    void BeginAcceptTcpClient()
    {
        server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(x =>
        {
        var remoteClient = server.EndAcceptTcpClient(x);
        BeginAcceptTcpClient();
        var from = remoteClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        var binReader = new BinaryReader(remoteClient.GetStream());
        while (remoteClient.Connected)
        {
            var type = (MsgType)binReader.ReadByte();
                switch (type)
                {
                    case MsgType.Text:
                        var mtext = new MsgText(binReader);
                        this.Invoke(param, new object[] { from + ": " + mtext.Text + "\r\n" });
                        break;
                    case MsgType.File:
                        var mFile = new MsgFile(binReader);
                        this.Invoke(param, new object[] { string.Format("{0}: файл \"{1}\" Размер {2}б \r\n", from, mFile.Name, mFile.FileLen) });
                        if (MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} отправил файл \"{1}\", размер {2} б. Принять?", from, mFile.Name, mFile.FileLen), "Прием файла", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            var saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                            saveDialog.FileName = mFile.Name;
                            if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                            {
                                using (var file = saveDialog.OpenFile())
                                {
                                    new BinaryWriter(file).Write(mFile.File);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, null);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (client.Connected) client.Close();
            client.Connect(textBoxIP.Text, 20113);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream()).Write((byte)MsgType.Text);
        new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream()).Write(textBoxMsg.Text);
        textBoxChat.AppendText("Я: " + textBoxMsg.Text + " \r\n");
        textBoxMsg.Clear();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using(var file = openDialog.OpenFile())
            {
                var mFile = new MsgFile()
                {
                    Name = openDialog.SafeFileName,
                    FileLen = (int)file.Length,
                    File = new BinaryReader(file).ReadBytes((int)file.Length)
                };
                mFile.Write(client.GetStream());
            }
        }
    }
    enum MsgType: byte
    {
        Text,
        File
    }
    struct MsgText
    {
        public string Text;
        public MsgText(BinaryReader br)
        {
            Text = br.ReadString();
        }
    }
    struct MsgFile
    {
        public string Name;
        public int FileLen;
        public byte[] File;

        public MsgFile(BinaryReader br)
        {
            Name = br.ReadString();
            FileLen = br.ReadInt32();
            File = br.ReadBytes(FileLen);
        }
        public void Write(Stream s)
        {
            var bw = new BinaryWriter(s);
            bw.Write((byte)MsgType.File);
            bw.Write(Name);
            bw.Write(FileLen);
            bw.Write(File);
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image: Структура файла]
[image: Структура сообщения]

Answer (score 1):

Первым байтом в потоке закодирован тип

```
var type = (MsgType)binReader.ReadByte();
switch (type) { ... }
```

Где 0 - это Text, 1 - это File, см. соответствующий Enum:

```
enum MsgType : byte
{
    Text,
    File
}
```

(Напоминаю, что в Enum по умолчанию идёт нумерация от нуля)

Когда вам нужно сформировать сообщение, то вы первым делом кладёте тип, например для случая текста:

```
new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream()).Write((byte)MsgType.Text);
```

А потом уже само сообщение:

```
new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream()).Write(textBoxMsg.Text);
```

То же самое и в случае формирования сообщения с файлом.

Сначала записали тип:

```
bw.Write((byte)MsgType.File);
```

Потом всё остальное.

Можете считать, что у вас есть конверт (envelope) для сообщения (message), который состоит из типа (text или file) и содержимого. Поскольку код у вас неструктурированный, то вы эту абстракцию не видите, а был пример посложнее - могли бы отдельно сделать упаковку/распаковку сообщения в конверт для передачи сообщения по сети. Скажем, автоматически считать и проверять контрольную сумму. Используя паттерны, можно было бы избавиться от этого switch и безболезненно расширять архитектуру другими типами сообщений...

При этом в вопросе вы приводите именно какие варианты сообщений бывают, забыв привести структуру для "конверта" - потому что тот, кто писал программу не стал писать такие тривиальные на его взгляд мелочи.