# c# сокеты клиент-сервер

Tags: c#, сокет, клиент-сервер, сокеты

У меня небольшая проблемка в работе с клиент-сервером.

Суть задания в том, что мне нужно, чтобы клиент ввел номер строки и текст, который будет записан в текстовый файл, а этот файл должен хранится на сервере. 
Клиент и сервер у меня сами работают нормально, да и как записать в нужную строку текст, я знаю.

Не могу понять только как мне связать клиента и сервера во время записи в файл т.к., при передаче от клиента к серверу, не могу нормально преобразовать типы сообщения в byte.

Подскажите как мне связать клиента и сервер при такой задаче.

Клиент

```
class Program
{
    static Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        socket.Connect("127.0.0.1",904);
        Console.WriteLine("Vvedite nomerk stroki");
        int number_line =Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Vvedite text");
        string line_text = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] buffer1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(number_line);
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line);
        socket.Send(buffer);
        socket.Send(buffer1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Сервер

```
class Program
{
    static Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 904));
        socket.Listen(5);
        Socket client = socket.Accept();
        Console.WriteLine("Подключение к серверу");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        byte[] buffer1 = new byte[1024];
        client.Receive(buffer1);
        client.Receive(buffer);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer1));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Запись в текстовый файл по номеру строки

```
var text = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt").ToList();
text.Insert(number_line,line_text);
File.WriteAllLines("1.txt", text.ToArray());
```

Comment: Если  правильно уловил суть вопроса, то посмотрите [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774137/213987): структура пакета (чтобы можно было передавать произвольное число байт, а не 1024) и сделайте по аналогии для своего транспорта. И жаль, что у вас есть вставка _строк_: можно было бы меньше туда-сюда конвертаций сделать, не гоняя байты в строки и обратно, ограничиться File.ReadAllBytes/File.WriteAllBytes

Comment: В целом мне нужно сделать задание. Суть задания в том, что мне нужно, чтобы клиент ввел номер строки и текст, который будет записан в текстовый файл, а этот файл должен хранится на сервере.
Я знаю как сделать все части отдельно, но как совместить их воединно не знаю. Вот в целом вопрос в чем.